# How to set the 6th bit of ADMUX on ATmega328P in AVR assembly language?

Tags: avr, atmega

I'm trying to initialise ADC. First thing is to enable Vref. For that I need to set 6th bit of ADMUX.

Things I have tried:

---

```
sbi ADMUX, 6
```

error: `I/O out of range (0 <= P <= 31)`

---

```
ldi r16, 0b01000000
out ADMUX, r16
```

error: `I/O out of range (0 <= P <= 63)`

---

What do these errors even mean ??
Please someone help!!

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. Here's the problem:

Looking at "`m328Pdef.inc`", `ADMUX` is `0x7C`. So your
`out ADMUX, r16`
is like writing
`out 0x7C, r16`.

`out` and `sbi` cannot "reach" that address (`0x7C`). That's exactly why you are getting those cryptic `out of range` errors.

Looking at the [ATMEL documentaion](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_OUT.html), `out` is meant to `Store Register to I/O Location`. It can only access addresses that fall under I/O space.
`ADMUX`, `ADCSRA`, etc do NOT fall under I/O space.
`PortA`, `PortB`, etc fall under I/O space.

So, we just need to find a command which can reach/access the address `0x7C`. One such is [`sts` command](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_STS.html).

`sts` can reach anywhere! But it also takes 2 cycles to complete.

You can solve your problem by writing:

```
ldi r16, 0b01000000
sts ADMUX, r16
```